# Error in Cygwin for Moai Android Build

Tags: shell, cygwin, moai

I'm following [this](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2012/08/28/Setting-up-a-Moai-Android-host-build-environment.aspx) tutorial set to set up Moai for Android porting. When I run

```
./make-host.sh –p com.gamefromscratch.moai
```

in Cygwin to build the Android host it returns an error of

```
build.sh: line 17: ndk-build: command not found
```

I'm 98% certain everything has installed correctly and I've been following the instructions exactly as written. When I look in the shell script line 17 is

```
use_fmod="false"
```

I've never had to use shell scripts or set up anything like this before and my scouring of the internet has failed to yield a result.

As a side note, Moai runs perfectly and I haven't had any problems with getting that to work.

Comment: You need to verify that ndk-build is in your path. Try `echo $PATH` from the cygwin command line. It should have something like `c:\android-ndk` in it depending on where you installed the Android NDK

Comment: The ndk-build is showing up in path. I went through adding everything to the path just to be safe and I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the issue! When I went to look for the environment variable in Windows (Computer -> right click -> properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables), I found that the variable path was there but was listed as **‘%PATH;c:\android-ndk’**. As an experiment I changed it to just **c:\android-ndk** and rebooted the computer. I then ran the line to have the host run and it ran through the process without a hitch. The only difference is that instead of **untitled-host** my file is called **host-source** and instead of **settings-local.sh** my file is called **d.settings-local.sh**. Outside of those minor file name changes everything else is the same.

Comment: Ah that would do it. The instructions are probably confusing. `PATH=%PATH;c:\android-ndk` is suppose to take the current path `%PATH` and append `c:\android-ndk` to it. Congrats on solving your problem.